# What commands should be used to map a key to a list using the table extension?

Tags: netlogo

I have recently started using the table extension as a means to assign numbers to a list with the same name. I have created a table

```
   table:put id-numbers X
```

and each time the command block is run a variable X is incremented and added to the table.

How do you map the added key to a list, without creating a whole new list that is only composed of the items within the table like when using `table:to-list` ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking.  Note that `table:put` takes *3* arguments, and the last can be any list you want (including the empty list).  If you want to append a value to the list, you need to e.g. `table:put tname key (lput newval table:get tname key)`.  hth.

Comment: Is it possible to use  `foreach`  to be able to record the key of each list by using `set variable1 table:get tname key`  where the key is the number label of the list.

Comment: Try to say clearly what you are trying to do.  I still cannot tell.  If you just want the keys, use `table:keys tname`, which gives you a list of keys.  But usually you will not need this.

Comment: I am trying to assign incrementally increasing numbers to a lists which will all have the same name. The purpose of this will be not having to define loads of different lists in the global and not having a fixed number of lists to fill. In your answer on my other question you mentioned about mapping keys to lists, and I am unsure how to do this. I am then unsure about how to read the key associated with a list once it has been mapped to the list.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the use of a table is that you do not need to construct global names for each list.  Here is a silly example.  (Silly, because you should just use a turtle attribute instead.)  But hopefully it sheds light on your question.

```
extensions [table]
globals [mytable]

to setup
  set mytable table:make
  crt 10 [table:put mytable who []]
end

to go
  ;;do stuff
  ask turtles [
    table:put mytable who (lput getval (table:get mytable who))
  ]
end

to-report getval ;;turtle proc
  ;;do stuff
  report result
end
```